# Правильный перенос строки в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, list, print

Подскажите, есть список с фразами, но они длинные и *PEP8* ругается за длину строки.

Часть фразы переношу символом **`\`** , но тогда он считает и все пробелы.

Пример:

```
list_of_words = ["The weather is good.",
                 "Hot dog is the best food, \
                 it would be a sure sign that it was still yummy.",
                 "The girls are beautiful.",
                 "Текст любой, не важно, но после бэкслэша огромное \
                 расстояние между словами. Как это исправить?"]
print(*list_of_words)
```

Вывод:

```
The weather is good. Hot dog is the best food,                  it would be a sure sign that it was still yummy. The girls are beautiful. Текст любой, не важно, но после бэкслэша огромное                  растояние между словами. Как это исправить?
```

Как избежать этой ерунды?

**P.S.**

Можно написать конечно так, но есть другой способ?

```
list_of_words = ["The weather is good.",
                 "Hot dog is the best food, \
it would be a sure sign that it was still yummy.",
                 "The girls are beautiful.",
                 "Текст любой, не важно, но после бэкслэша огромное \
растояние между словами. Как это исправить?"]
print(*list_of_words)
```

Comment: `list_of_words` значит «список **слов**», а у вас список **предложений** (`list_of_sentences`).

Comment: Чтобы иметь полное представление о переносе строк мне помогла эта статья https://tirinox.ru/new-line/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
list_of_words = [
    "The weather is good.",
    
    "Hot dog is the best food,"
    "it would be a sure sign that it was still yummy.",
    
    "The girls are beautiful.",
    
    "Текст любой, не важно, но после бэкслэша огромное "
    "расстояние между словами. Как это исправить?"
]

print(*list_of_words)
print()
print(*list_of_words, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот так, например:

```
list_of_words = ["The weather is good.",
                 "Hot dog is the best food, " +
                 "it would be a sure sign that it was still yummy.",
                 "The girls are beautiful.",
                 "Текст любой, не важно, но после бэкслэша огромное " +
                 "расстояние между словами. Как это исправить?"]
```

Answer (score 0):

есть вариант писать символ \n для переноса строки .

```
list_of_words = ["The weather is good.",
                 "Hot dog is the best food,\n
                 it would be a sure sign that it was still yummy.",
                 "The girls are beautiful.",
                 "Текст любой, не важно, но после бэкслэша огромное \n
                 расстояние между словами. Как это исправить?"]

print(*list_of_words)
```

Comment: Будьте добры дать более развёрнутый ответ

Comment: Тут речь не об этом